# Regex to find a line that contains one string and does not contain another in NPP find

Tags: regex, search, logging, text, notepad++

I have a really huge log file from which i need to search stuff. All the relevant logging has the message "main.tables" but there are too many such messages too. What I want is, to remove certain statements from my search results (while in NPP) that contain "START" or "END".

I am looking for is a complete regex based solution rather than code based.

Comment: can you show some lines, how it looks?

Comment: sorry that's confidential. but i think all the info is in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from [markantoniou-regex](http://markantoniou.blogspot.com/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html) step 9

sign

> ^

searches inverse so include inverse + start,end accordingly, hope it helps, i don't have your log to try it